# Authorization headers error while getting jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get json data from the Bing Search API.

What I have done is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var appId = ':mykey';


function getNews() {

//console.log("DF");
var azureKey = btoa(appId);
var myUrl = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=%27britain%27&$format=json';

$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  url: myUrl,
  dataType:"jsonp"

  //Set headers to authorize search with Bing
  headers:{'Authorization':'Basic ' + azureKey      }
  }
  success: function(data) {

   console.log("DF");
   //console.log(data);
   var json = data.d.results[1].Url;    
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = json;
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, error, textStatus) { console.error(jqXHR, error, textStatus); }

});
};

getNews();

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to run this, the following error comes in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

for the line

```
headers:{'Authorization':'Basic ' + azureKey      }
```

I have the following doubts:

1. Whether I am doing the jsonp thing right?
2. Whether I am correct in including two scripts:

language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.js"> and the main script.

And of course, why the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is a missing comma

```
dataType:"jsonp",
//              ^
```

You also have an extra `}` after the headers object, which will be another syntax error, change that to a comma.

```
    headers:{'Authorization':'Basic ' + azureKey      }
    ,
//  ^ comma not a }
```

You won't be able to use the `authorization` header with JSONP, it is not possible. If the service supports CORS (which it looks like it does) then you can use a normal XHR by setting the dataType to `json`.